# Can I "fix" misplaced HTML tags using PHP?

Tags: php, html

Is there a quick and easy way to fix HTML tags that are misplaced, in a web document? Such as:

```
<strong><span style="border:1px;">Text</strong></span>
   /\                                    /\
   |______________________________________|
```

So that it looks like:

```
<strong><span style="border:1px;">Text</span></strong>
```

Edit: you are suggesting HTML fixers, but what I'm looking for is a function type solution. Would it help if you could consider this to be BBcode? `[b][u]Text[\b][\u]`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is using [Html Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), works pretty good:

Demo: http://htmlpurifier.org/demo.php

Works with your input perfectly.

Comment: It works on a simple example such as this one, but I do have more complex structures and it fails on them ..

Comment: @Matt There are many HTML fixers out there, check them out. Without some examples of what isn't working for you with htmlpurifier it is hard to recommend another one.

Answer (score 0):

How should a computer know whether you meant for the `span` to be inside the `strong`, or the other way around?

The "quick and easy way" is to run your document through an HTML validator, then fix the issues that it identifies using your noggin and keyboard.

Comment: Priority given to the first open tag would be a good start, even though it would fail markup wise, but would function regardless

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tidy::repairFile()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairfile.php) or [tidy::repairString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php), but repairing is not straightforward, so you can never be sure the result will be what you expect. Example from the documentation:

```
<?php
$file = 'file.html';

$tidy = new tidy();
$repaired = $tidy->repairfile($file);
rename($file, $file . '.bak');

file_put_contents($file, $repaired);
?>
```